# How to show info about selected point on scatter - to a textbox in GUIDE

Tags: matlab, cursor

I've a struct array of information, like

```
S.a { 'smth1', 'smth2.... }
S.b { x1, x2, .... }
S.c {y1, y2, ....}
S.d ...... etc
scater(S.b, S.c)
```

And now, when I select point 
(for ex  - x1,y1) 
on scatter plot - 
i want to show info about this point - to textbox
 like

" x1 = ... y1 = ....

smth1 = .... etc.

Comment: Please Without Ginput

Answer (score 0):

I will skip the whole GUIDE part here, i.e. transferring the obtained value to some Text box, and focus on how to retrieve the desired data.

There's the [`ginput`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) function in MATLAB, which you can use to capture the `x, y` coordinates of your mouse cursor within MATLAB figures. So, now the idea is to capture the `x, y` coordinates by clicking inside the scatter plot, set up some tolerance (e.g. `0.1`), and find matching `x, y` coordinates in `S.a` and `S.b` within this tolerance.

I put together the following code example:

```matlab
% Set up proper struct
S.a = {'First Point', 'Point #2', 'Point No. 3'};
S.b = [3.0, 5.2, 8.5];
S.c = [1.1, 0.4, 2.1]

% Show figure
hFig = figure;
scatter(S.b, S.c);
xlim([0 10]);
ylim([0 3]);
text(0.6, 2.7, 'Press ESC to exit', 'FontSize', 16);

while (true)

  % Get x, y coordinates and possibly pressed button
  [x, y, button] = ginput(1);

  % If ESC button was pressed, exit loop
  if (button == 27)
    break;
  end

  % Display x, y coordinates  
  fprintf('x: %f, y: %f\n', x, y);

  % Find matching point within a certain tolerance
  idx = find((abs(S.b - x) <= 0.1) & (abs(S.c - y) <= 0.1));

  % If an index was found, display description
  if (~isempty(idx))
    fprintf('Matching point: %s\n-----------------------------\n', S.a{idx});
  else
    fprintf('No matching point\n------------------------------\n');
  end

end
```

For visualization purposes, this is an infinite loop, capturing the `x, y` coordinates once per iteration. As you can use `ginput` also to identify possible keys pressed, the exit condition is the ESC key pressed. The rest is the above described finding of possible matching coordinates from `S.a` and `S.b`, and some output formatting.

After loading the figure, some clicking inside the scatter plot gives for example:

```
x: 2.769585, y: 1.109754
No matching point
------------------------------
x: 3.023041, y: 1.100948
Matching point: First Point
-----------------------------
x: 6.317972, y: 1.189010
No matching point
------------------------------
x: 5.211982, y: 0.414066
Matching point: Point #2
-----------------------------
x: 8.529954, y: 2.113658
Matching point: Point No. 3
-----------------------------
```

The possibly found value `S.a{idx}` now just needs to be sent to your desired Text box.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! This is work, but a little different way, as i wanted.

Comment: @ЕвгенийФедоров You can always [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58536000/edit), and provide further details.

Comment: Thank you! This is worked, but a little different way, as i wanted. Ginput is good, but i don't need tolerance about selected dot.lets say I have a scatter plot about group of students and their grades on 2 subjectcs:Math/Physics - so the first student got 3.0 - math and 1.1 phys.When i'm select dot №1 i want to display - his name, department and this 2 grades.So i need to exact values of this grades from my struct array.Besides, ginput selector - is huge and ugly thing "+". all over my GUIDE app.

Comment: Maybe i need use "datacursormode" and do smthg with that?I've already datatip with all I need on the graf.But I need to show this info in separeted textbox or smth like that outside of my graf.

Comment: Then please add all what you have so far to your question in terms of a [mre]. If you already have a working solution to obtain the right values, and just need the matching back to your structure, than the last part of my solution, i.e. finding the proper index, should be sufficient.